# Peewee Meta class inherence

Tags: orm, peewee, flask-peewee

I am struggling with the following:

```
from my_db_definition import db
from peewee import *
class A(Model):
    class Meta:
        database=db
        table_name = 'random'
        
class B(A):
    pass
```

when running

```
print(A._meta.table_name)
print(B._meta.table_name)
random
b
```

My question is now, why is the table name changed in this case, and can this be prevented? I am completely confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#model-options-and-table-metadata

The docs list which options are inherited and which are not.

Only certain attributes are passed to the subclass via the inner "Meta" class. It's purpose is 1) namespacing, and 2) provide conventions around DRY code.

table name is not inherited because presumably you only want one class-per-table, whereas database **is** inherited because it makes sense to only declare that once.